# JQM page transition not working in Trigger.io app

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, transition, trigger.io

Iam using Trigger.io framework to write an app for ios and android using Jquery Mobile. Iam having touble changing the pages using $.mobile.changePage(); function. It seems like the function wont work when run in android device. Shows an "Error Loading Page" alert. It wud be great if some one could tell me why it is not working
JQuery Mobile version - 1.4.5

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="login" id="facebooklogin" data-role="button" >Facebook Login</a>


$('#facebooklogin').live('click',function(){
forge.facebook.authorize(function () {
   $.mobile.changePage("#review",{
      transition:"slide",
      reverse: false
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: Please show us more code and markup and tell us what versions of jQuery and jQuery Mobile you are using. Also if you can create a jsFiddle, that is often helpful in the debugging process.

Comment: Have you confirmed that authorize is succeeding and firing the callback? In jQM 1.4, you should use the pagecontainer widget's change method to navigate: http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-change, here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/yw475tf8/

Comment: Yeah .. the login is working .. let me try out the code u posted .. will get back to u ..

Comment: Thank you so much. i shifted to AngularJS. Its brilliant !